# Can I provide multiple copies of a VSTO document-level Excel app without publishing each one separately?

Tags: excel, vsto

I have created an Excel document-level customization in Visual Studio 2017 using Windows 7. The document provides a set of tools for charting and analyzing data that are contained in several worksheets within the document.

I would like to provide the end user multiple versions of this document without publishing each one separately. Each version differs only in the data that will be contained. All the code, classes, subs, and functions would be identical for each version.  I was hoping they could
rely on the same assembly.

I tested this by publishing a document (named DocumentA) on a test PC (Windows10) and then copying an additional file (named DocumentB). Trying to open DocumentB in Excel produces the following error:

Could not load assembly "DocumentA", Version 1.0.0.0.  Culture =Neutral or one of its dependencies.  The System could not find the file specified.

I think I understand why this happens.  However, if I save the original published document DocumentA as DocumentB1, I can open the renamed file 
with no problem. Not sure why this works and the other case does not.  The property settings for assembly name and location were identical for DocumentA and DocumentB.

Is there any type of work-around? Or must I publish each of these additional documents separately?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you replace A with B exactly? Can you provide more detail? I suspect this is possible, although as Eugene notes, an application-level add-in might be more appropriate.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. I just changed the data for some of the worksheets in A and saved as B.  No changes to any code.

Comment: Way, way, way more detail, please. A numbered list of steps would be great. Something like this: (1) Publish DocumentA in folder ABC (2) Open DocumentA, I can see my ribbon buttons (3) Modify data (4) Save as DocumentB in folder XYZ (5) Close DocumentB (6) Re-open Document B, got error X and can't see my ribbon buttons. Obviously that's not the right set of steps, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to provide the end user multiple versions of this document without publishing each one separately.

You need to create separate document level add-ins then. Or you may consider developing a single application-level add-in instead. See [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-excel?view=vs-2019) for more information.